# How do I use gulp with an component angularjs folder structure?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I've been starting to think I might add gulp to my development process.

I've read this article: http://mherman.org/blog/2014/08/14/kickstarting-angular-with-gulp/

I realize that this is using the "seed structure".

```
/app
 app.js
 /js
  /controllers
   loginController.js
 /partials
  login.html
 ...
```

However I want to use the component structure:

```
/app
 app.js
 /login
  loginController.js
  login.html
 ...
```

Does anyone know of good resources for this? I've been googling around and I haven't found anything. Perhaps I'm not using the right terms.

Comment: Since the linting, minifying, etc. of files occurs for all within './app/**/*.js' (or html, or css), which will look for all JS files within all folders under app, regardless of how nested they are, then it doesn't matter what file structure you choose to use. If you want to read about the "seed structure" directory concept then go here: http://www.johnpapa.net/structuring-an-angular-project/. If you want to read more about the component structure then check out the links in the comments (there is some lively debate there also :) )

Comment: @horyd The only thing about this is that in the routes file you define where the template is. How is this handled? I don't see anyone discussing this..

Comment: Since you specified the location of the files use glob syntax, gulp will maintain the directory structure when the files are piped into the dist folder. So when you write your routes you define your template path exactly as they exist within your "app" folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can make whatever structure you want, All you have to you modify the tasks destination in your **gulpfile.js** likewise, For example

```
gulp.task('copy-html-files', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

will copy all the .html files under **./app/**/** to folder **dist/** you can change the destination if you want